# maps on my own server with google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to make a website that displays my map, has panning, zooming and other features. 
The google API seems to be the right thing for me. Just one question : Can i use the google javascript api with my own map images on my own server. I dont want to use the actual google maps, just its capability to display zoomable/scrollable maps in a browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically this may be possible using the Overlays section ([Ground overlays](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#GroundOverlays) allow image overlays on the map) of the API and hooking half a dozen events to handle the redrawing at different zoom levels, tiling, hiding the real information about whatever location Google Maps thinks it is showing, etc.

But it is definitely not designed for such purposes and I'm not sure if it would be legal to use it in that way, would have to read the license.

There are other alternatives out there that would be able to achieve this functionality without the level of work needed to get Google Maps to cooperate I believe.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don’t think so.

You may also want to look at [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/). I have seen custom map-images being used with its interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that the Google maps interactivity code is geared towards working with Google map servers for the underlying map. However, you **could put your own layers over their maps** and then serve up your own content so long as it used the same mapping co-ordinates.